# firebase + create-react-app hosting error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, syntax-error, firebase-hosting

i was trying to deploy my react SPA on Firebase, but got only blank page with such console error:
**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"**

[chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeTCR.png)
[chrome_elements_blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mqK2.png)

to exclude third part libraries I created new React-app to deploy. and got exactly same problem.

terminal log:

[part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2lNp.png)
[part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GZph.png)

[part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I57aq.png)
[part4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FYWx.png)

anybody knows how to fix this?

[link to firebase deployed create-react-app start page](https://mmstarz-react16-demo.firebaseapp.com/)

Code from firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [ 
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [ 
      {
        "source" : "*",
        "destination" : "/index.html"
      } 
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: every time i try to copy/paste code it's transformed inline here((

Comment: Please include your error(s), code and database structure as text instead of an image.

Comment: Added the full solution. If that helps you, please feel free to upvote the answer and mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your main.js contains the page html data again. 
`<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head>...`.

As the browser loads the JS file and tries to interpret it, it fails, as HTML is clearly not javascript. It tries to communicate its confusion with "*Oh I found a < but that is not what I expected*".

You seem to have configured a default route for your server and each and any request returns your index.html.

I noticed in one of your screenshots, that you said "yes" to "*Rewrite all urls to index.html*" - it does exactly that. You should not activate that, as ALL you requests will then always return the `index.html`.

Please have a look in your `firebase.json` file. You will find the instructions for hosting and routing in there.

**API Docs are here:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

You might want to have a special look into the redirects array, looking like this:

```
"redirects": [ 
  {
    "source" : "*",
    "destination" : "/index.html"
  } 
]
```

Here you tell the server to redirect all traffic to `/index.html`. Delete the redirect entries, redeploy and all will be well.

So this redirects section will most probably solve the issue:

```
{
  "hosting": {
   "public": "build",
   "ignore": [ 
     "firebase.json",
     "**/.*",
     "**/node_modules/**"  
    ],
    "redirects": []
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. there is no specific code here. just standart create-react-app start page. about HTML and JS i thought it's what babel do. translate jsx  for browser to understand. so you suggest to change firebase initial props?

Comment: There is a firebase.json for example. I am betting, the instructions in what to server is in there. Added that to the answer.

Comment: Added the obvious to my answer after inspecting the contents of the firebase.json image

Comment: I tried this- my redirects was empty, but i had the same entries in my rewrites array. I'm running out of things to try so I tried deleting those and redeploying - but I still get the blank page.

Comment: @Mel did you resolve the issue? I am trying every StackOverflow solution and still couldn't get it working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BEAGLE - I'm sorry that I don't remember the details of this particular problem. Based on the timing though, I think I did keep going with firebase - so there must be a solution. I did give up on trying to figure out how to use Firebase though. I spent a year trying to work out how to use dates. The documentation is neatly formatted, but the substance of it is unclear. Good luck.

Comment: @Mel I did solve the issue. When I looked back at my HTML, all the reference links were pointing to [project-name]/[folder-name]/[file-name]. This worked in git-pages but for firebase hosting, I had to remove the project-name because I was only hosting the "dist" folder.

Comment: @BEAGLE - that sounds familiar - well done

Answer (score 3):

This also can be an issue in the `package.json` file, if you have set the attribute `homepage`

```
   {
    "name": "project-name",
    "homepage": "https://project-url",
    "version": "0.1.0",
   }
```

to solve this issue remove the `homepage` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

thanks everyone for quick reply. problem was solved with adding `"redirects":[]` to firebase.json like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [],        
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding redirects: [] to my firebase.json file, but I still get the blank page.

Comment: As your code might differ, I would advise to create a new question.

Comment: This is a dangerous response as i would assume a lot of users might have created "redirects" for that exact purpose..redirecting - changing it without evaluating the consequences might not be so wise IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

100% Working Example.

Solved  Blank Page Error  in React App Hosting in Firebase .

You can read this  [blog](https://easytechnolearn.blogspot.com/2019/05/fixed-blank-page-problem-after.html)

Host Your React Web App in few minutes.

*Command runnning in Wrong sequence =>*

> **firebase login**
>
> **firebase init**
>
> **firebase deploy**
>
> **npm run build**

*Command runnning in Correct sequence =>*

> **firebase login**
>
> **firebase init**
>
> **npm run build**
>
> **firebase deploy**

Comment: For detail explaination click on the above  link

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply change firebase.json to use the build folder instead of public:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvZG9.png)

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included the json in your answer instead of a screenshot.

Comment: might be different for everyone. only thing you should take from my screenshot is the "public" : "build" as mine was "public" : "public" before